# Ubuntu USB Does not load grub bootloader

Tags: grub2

My Ubuntu USB does not load grub boot loader, the Ubuntu ISO hash is d14cb9b6f48feda0563cda7b5335e4c0. It worked fine on my old DELL laptop, but not my personal computer, my computer has:

- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3570 @ 3.40GHz 3401 Mhz 4 cores,
- 16 GB of ram,
- HP Dashboard Product 3397,
- Windows Currently installed,
- K01 HP v03.06 2/12/2018 BIOS,
- no virtualization supported

I am trying to boot to my Cruzer Glide 32 GB, (actually 28 GB), does anyone know the commands to load the kernel and boot to Ubuntu Installer?
I used rufus to flash the usb drive, MBR partiton scheme, Bios or UEFI, fat32 filesystem, 16kb cluster size.

Comment: What program did you use to make the USB drive? Perhaps you are trying to boot in UEFI mode on a BIOS computer?

Comment: i think i have a BIOS computer, how do I boot in bios mode?

Comment: also I CANT enter the bios settings / firmware settings, it will not allow me

Comment: An i5-3570 should be an UEFI based computer, even if HP calls it BIOS. If Windows preinstall, then it would be UEFI. Have you updated to latest UEFI/BIOS from HP? You need to create installer in UEFI/gpt boot mode if using Rufus and boot in UEFI mode on HP.

Comment: thanks ill try it in gpt/uefi mode

Comment: UPDATE: it went straight to the grub terminall

Comment: i am surprised none has tried to comment